# using do-while loop and finding the difference between 2 numbers

Tags: java

I'm attempting to create a program that randomly generates a number between 1 and 10,000 then divides this number by 100 to create another number that the user is then supposed to enter the change for. (67.48 would b x amount of 20's, 5's, 1's, Quarters, etc., etc.)...if the user enters an incorrect number in their answer the program is supposed to display the difference between their answer and the random number. There's nothing in the glossary about differences or finding them...and I've never made a do-while loop as extensive as the one we're currently losing. I need some assistance finding what I'm doing wrong.

```
// ---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7
// 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ChangeGame
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int low = 1;
      int max = 10000;
      int twentyDollars = 0;
      int tenDollars = 0;
      int fiveDollars = 0;
      int oneDollar = 0;
      int quarters = 0;
      int dimes = 0;
      int nickels = 0;
      int pennies = 0;
      Random random = new Random();
      int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - low + 1);
      double randomNumber1 = (randomNumber /100.0); 

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      do  
      {
         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Twenties: "); 
         twentyDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( twentyDollars < 0 );
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Twenties: " );
            twentyDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Tens: "); 
         tenDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( tenDollars <= 1 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Tens: " );
            tenDollars = keyboard.nextInt(); 
         }

         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Fives: "); 
         fiveDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( fiveDollars <= 1 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Fives: " );
            fiveDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Ones: "); 
         oneDollar = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( oneDollar <= 4 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Ones: " );
            oneDollar = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Quarters: "); 
         quarters = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( quarters <= 3 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Quarters: " );
            quarters = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Dimes: "); 
         dimes = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( dimes <= 2 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Dimes: " );
            dimes = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Nickels: "); 
         nickels = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( nickels <= 1 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Nickels: " );
            nickels = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

         System.out.println("Enter the change for " + randomNumber1);
         System.out.println("Pennies: "); 
         pennies = keyboard.nextInt();
         while( pennies <= 4 )
         {
            System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
               "Pennies: " );
            pennies = keyboard.nextInt();
         }

      while( difference != 0);
         {
            System.out.println("Incorrect by: ");
         }
   } 
}​
```

Comment: When you say "what I'm doing wrong", you would help us help you if you stated what the output / results are and what is incorrect about them.  Then it is easier to home in on faults in the program.

Comment: well, currently I have no idea of how to find the difference between the amount the user will enter and the random number that has been generated by the program.

Comment: Ok.  "Difference" is synonymous with "subtraction" in this way:  Subtraction produces the difference.  Either work in integer cents (a good idea) or in floating point dollars (can lead to single cent discrepancies -- not good for accounting).  When printing of course format integer cents to dollars and cents.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one error (not sure if it's the only one) :

Change

```
     while( twentyDollars < 0 );
                               ^
     {
        System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
           "Twenties: " );
        twentyDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
     }
```

to

```
     while( twentyDollars < 0 )
     {
        System.out.println( "** Invalid Amount **\n" +
           "Twenties: " );
        twentyDollars = keyboard.nextInt();
     }
```

`while( twentyDollars < 0 );` may be an infinite loop (if `twentyDollars < 0` initially).

EDIT :

You have another error here :

```
  while( difference != 0);
  {
      System.out.println("Incorrect by: ");
  }
```

It looks like this `while` is meant to end to do-while loop. If that's the case, you are missing a `}` :

```
}
while (difference != 0);
```

And it's not clear what the following

```
{
    System.out.println("Incorrect by: ");
}
```

is intended to do. It has no relation to the while statement that precedes it.

Comment: Note, since the answer is not clear (though the exercise of finding it is useful), that the alteration is to delete a semicolon on the first line of the fragment.

Comment: thank you, I didn't realize that. i'm still receiving two errors ChangeGame.java:120: error: while expected
   } 
    ^
ChangeGame.java:121: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
2 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: @L-G:  You may be missing a curly brace:  { or }.  Count them up and down:  Add one for each { and subtract one for each }.  You should have a count of zero at the end of the program.  Another useful technique is to comment each closing curly brace referencing the control statement that opened it, like:  "} // while (twentyDollars < 0)".

Comment: i'm counting the braces and it's uneven but I cant find where tf the missing or extra brace should b....

Comment: okay, now for whatever damn reason no matter what I put in, it claims i'm entering an invalid amount when I enter the amount of 20s and causing me to enter the input twice? why is that